# Stop Ubuntu keyboard shortcuts from "resurrecting"

Tags: shortcut-keys

I use a good deal of the default Ubuntu shortcuts as shortcuts in Emacs (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> is the most important). I obviously have disabled these shortcuts in the keyboard shortcuts dialog, but for whatever reason, they sometimes "come back", generally after I've installed/uninstalled certain packages, or upgraded Ubuntu.

My question therefore is: how do I keep these shortcuts disabled? I don't want shortcuts like <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> restored for any reason.

Comment: No one? :( I did a software update (no new installed packages) and again Alt-Space as well Ctrl-Alt-Arrows have reappeared. So annoying.

Comment: Agreed! Maybe you can add something to your login script.

Comment: That is one of the reasons that I use fluxbox as my window manager. There, the keyboard shortcuts can be edited in a text file and moved around different machines.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ubuntu bugs in launchpad about keyboard shortcuts settings being reset to default.

It seems that when you switch the 'Backend' setting to 'Flat-file Configuration Backend' in CompizConfig Settings Manager under 'Preferences', the keyboard shortcuts changes seem persistent. You'll have to do a unity --replace for the changes to take affect.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this 'Backend' option. Can you please edit your answer to tell us where the 'flat files' are stored?

Answer (score 0):

Try `gconf-editor` then search for the keybinding under **Edit** -> **Find** *search also in key values*
You should be able to find your keybinding here, then unset it or change it to something else

Comment: this does not answer the question